How can I add creation/deletion/updates of channels categories and roles to log the same as this code?
Trying to log the creation deletion and also updates of channels category's and roles so it would send a log to the modlog channel as a embed as the rest in the below code. I want be able to log the stuff as for my advance logging system on my discord bot
const { EmbedBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const { getSettings } = require("@schemas/Guild");

module.exports = async (client, oldGuild, newGuild) => {
    const settings = await getSettings(newGuild);
    const logChannel = settings.modlog_channel ? newGuild.channels.cache.get(settings.modlog_channel) : null;
    if (!logChannel) return;

    if (oldGuild.name !== newGuild.name) {
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle("Guild Name Updated")
            .setColor('#FF5733')
            .setDescription(`${newGuild.name}'s name has been updated`)
            .addFields(
                { name: "Old Name", value: `\`\`\`${oldGuild.name || 'None'}\`\`\``, inline: true },
                { name: "New Name", value: `\`\`\`${newGuild.name || 'None'}\`\`\``, inline: true }
            )
            .setFooter({ text: `${client.user.username}(${client.user.id})`, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }) })
            .setTimestamp();

        await logChannel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    } else if (oldGuild.iconURL() !== newGuild.iconURL()) {
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle("Icon Updated")
            .setColor('#FF5733')
            .setDescription(`${newGuild.name}'s icon has been updated`)
            .addFields(
                { name: "Old Icon", value: `\`\`\`${oldGuild.iconURL() ? oldGuild.iconURL() : 'None'}\`\`\``, inline: true },
                { name: "New Icon", value: `\`\`\`${newGuild.iconURL() ? newGuild.iconURL() : 'None'}\`\`\``, inline: true }
            )
            .setFooter({ text: `${client.user.username}`, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }) })
            .setTimestamp();

        await logChannel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    } else if (oldGuild.banner !== newGuild.banner) {
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle("Guild Banner Updated")
            .setColor('#FF5733')
            .setDescription(`${newGuild.name}'s banner has been updated`)
            .addFields(
                { name: "Old Banner", value: `\`\`\`${oldGuild.banner ? oldGuild.bannerURL() : 'None'}\`\`\``, inline: true },
                { name: "New Banner", value: `\`\`\`${newGuild.banner ? newGuild.bannerURL() : 'None'}\`\`\``, inline: true }
            )
            .setFooter({ text: `${client.user.username}`, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }) })
            .setTimestamp();

        await logChannel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    } else if (oldGuild.ownerId !== newGuild.ownerId) {
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle("Guild Owner Updated")
            .setColor('#FF5733')
            .setDescription(`${newGuild.name}'s owner has been updated`)
            .addFields(
                { name: "Old Owner", value: `\`\`\`${oldGuild.ownerId}\`\`\``, inline: true },
                { name: "New Owner", value: `\`\`\`${newGuild.ownerId}\`\`\``, inline: true }
            )
            .setFooter({ text: `${client.user.username}`, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }) })
            .setTimestamp();

        await logChannel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    } else if (oldGuild.afkChannelId !== newGuild.afkChannelId) {
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle("AFK Channel Updated")
            .setColor('#FF5733')
            .setDescription(`${newGuild.name}'s AFK channel has been updated`)
            .addFields(
                { name: "Old AFK Channel", value: `\`\`\`${oldGuild.afkChannel || 'None'}\`\`\``, inline: true },
                { name: "New AFK Channel", value: `\`\`\`${newGuild.afkChannel || 'None'}\`\`\``, inline: true }
            )
            .setFooter({ text: `${client.user.username}`, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }) })
            .setTimestamp();

        await logChannel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    }
};


Want it to log changes into the same places as all otherlogs almost like Dyno discord bot

I assume the code you provided is the channelUpdate event you can use the channelCreate & channelDelete events for logging channel creation/deletion, for channel category change you can use the same logic you provided above using the parent property as well as the permissionOverwrites property for role permission updates.
